# OAuth2 userdetails not updating in spring security (SpringBoot)

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, jhipster

I am new to spring security and have used jhipster in which i have configured db and LDAP based authentications. Now i have integrated it with OAuth client using @enableOAuthSso. I can able to authenticate using external OAuth Idp (Okta) and it is redirecting to my application and my principle is getting updated and i can access resources through rest. But my userDetails object not getting populated.

```
@Inject
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    try {

        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAuthoritiesPopulator)
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .userDetailsContextMapper(ldapUserDetailsContextMapper)
            .contextSource(getLDAPContextSource());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
    }
}
```

I have check by going deep where its getting failed and found out the following

```
public static String getCurrentUserLogin() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    String userName = null;
    if (authentication != null) {
        log.info("authentication is not null");
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) { //failing here
            log.info("principle is instance of userdetails");
            UserDetails springSecurityUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            log.info(springSecurityUser.getUsername());
            userName = springSecurityUser.getUsername();
        } else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof String) {
            userName = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
    }
    return userName;
}
```

Its failing at the line

```
if(authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails)
```

What is the possible and the best way to handle this to update user details object.

**Update:**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public User getUserWithAuthorities() {
    log.info("======inside getUserWithAuthorities =================");
    log.info("current user is :::::::"+SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin());
    Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findOneByLogin(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin());
    User user = null;
    if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
        user = optionalUser.get();
        user.getAuthorities().size(); // eagerly load the association
    }
    return user;
}
```

Its trying to fetch the user from db. But the user is not present in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [the LDAP tip](https://jhipster.github.io/tips/016_tip_ldap_authentication.html), I would reocmmend creaing an OktaUserDetails class and casting the principal.  Then you can keep most of the authentication code the same.  The LDAP code example is below, the format of OktaUserDetails would depend on the JSON response

```
} else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof LdapUserDetails) {
    LdapUserDetails ldapUser = (LdapUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    return ldapUser.getUsername();
}
```

To save information received from an Oauth2 resource, declare a PrincipalExtractor Bean in your SecurityConfiguration.  This lets you parse the response in a custom manner.  A basic example is below ([source](http://mmkay.pl/2017/03/19/spring-boot-saving-oauth2-login-data-in-db-using-principalextractor/)).

```
@Bean
public PrincipalExtractor principalExtractor(UserRepository userRepository) {
    return map -> {
        String principalId = (String) map.get("id");
        User user = userRepository.findByPrincipalId(principalId);
        if (user == null) {
            LOGGER.info("No user found, generating profile for {}", principalId);
            user = new User();
            user.setPrincipalId(principalId);
            user.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
            user.setEmail((String) map.get("email"));
            user.setFullName((String) map.get("name"));
            user.setPhoto((String) map.get("picture"));
            user.setLoginType(UserLoginType.GOOGLE);
            user.setLastLogin(LocalDateTime.now());
        } else {
            user.setLastLogin(LocalDateTime.now());
        }
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    };
}
```

Comment: LDAP is working fine because on auth success i am replicating the user to application db. Actually problem is with the OAuth based authentication. In this case i am getting authenticated from okta but userdetails is not updated so my ui shows as i am anonymous user. I have tried in auth success handler but its not calling.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. It looks like you've figured out authentication is not null and that you know it's not an `instanceof UserDetails`.   Did you try adding an else clause and logging what `authentication.getPrincipal()` contains?

Comment: It's giving a string which has my first name and last name appended with space in between. You can see the actual json i get for principle [here](https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ev4eh). And the next point where it gets failed is in UserService.getUserWithAuthorities.

Comment: I thought of creating a new OktaUser and cast the principal to that user to fetch the necessary info and inject to User object in getUserWithAuthorities. Is that the best approach or shall i try to replicate the user to database which is little better to handle users and their roles in the application level and i am doing the same in LDAP. I tried with the authentication success handler but it is not getting triggered. I am not sure about that, should i have to configure SecurityConfig file for that? Any points on this.

Comment: I would base your decision off of what you want the "source of truth" to be.  If you import the authorities when logging in, then they change on Okta, the user could have extra privileges in your app (I haven't used Okta so this may be incorrect).

Comment: How can i capture the authentication success event. Basically i have jhipster provided ajaxauthsuccesshandler but its not getting triggered. Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: Have you tried implementing the PrincipalExtractor Bean?  That would let you parse the information returned by Okta and save it to the database.

Comment: I am not sure about it Jon can you provide some examples of that. Tried googling that but no luck. The main goal is to capture the auth success event from Okta which is configure through @EnableOauthSso. I have ket logger inside ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler which is given by Jhipster but no luck. Is there a workaround to create new success handler for OAuth2

Comment: I added an example PrincipalExtractor to the answer.